How to display react native expo app in full screen without statusbar
I tried to make a modal like a dynamic island which displays errors and messages.
When I tried to display the react native expo app in full screen by hiding the statusbar, the content of the statusbar got hidden but the statusbar got a black background and the app is also not getting displayed in full screen. I also tried setting the background transparent and translucent but it made no difference.

The code I have written to hide the status bar

<StatusBar hidden={true} translucent={true} />


I tried without hiding the status bar but the content of the status bar is displayed on top of the dynamic island. This is the code I tried.
//isLand Container 
<View style={{
    width:'100%',
    height:StatusBar.currentHeight,
    position:'absolute',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    zIndex:100,
}}>
    <>
        ...
    </>
</View>



I just want to display my app in full screen without status bar
